# What is Sakamoto doing holding those rods?

Tags: sakamoto-desu-ga

On page 3 of chapter 9, Sakamoto is walking while holding two rods in his hands. What is he trying to accomplish doing that?

[image: Sakamoto walking with two rods in his hands]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sakamoto is holding the L-shaped [dowsing rods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing), which are used to

> locate ground water, buried metals or ores, gemstones, oil, gravesites, and many other objects and materials.

[image: Two L-shaped metal wire rods]

The rods enable Sakamoto to:

- *physically* locate the trap set up by Acchan and his gang
- *spiritually* locate "points which require adjustment".

Comment: I'd say, in the end, it's similar to how a [divining rod](https://en.wikipedia.org/Dowsing) works. They often also have the symbolism of finding things other than water.